# Adding blank cell in dataframe based on column value (excel: insert cell and shift right)

Tags: python, pandas

For formatting purposes need to add blank cells in dataframe based on column value.  This is equivalent of what you see in excel with insert cell and shift cell right

I got it done using openpyxl and loop,  Steps I used

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb['sheet']

if 'SheetArranged' not in wb.sheetnames:
  wb.create_sheet('SheetArranged')
  wb.save('file.xlsx')
ws3 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SheetArranged')


b = 1
for i in range(1, ws.max_row):

'''
if lvl data is absent
'''

if lvl != None:
    lvl == lvl
else:
    lvl = 1

'''
indented data
'''

try:
    for j in range(1,5):
        ws3.cell(row = b, column = lvl+j+2).value = ws.cell(row = i, column = 3+j).value
except:
    pass
```

What I was looking for is a simpler way  I can achieve this in pandas

```
df>>

A    B    C
P1   1    C1
P2   3    C2
P3   2    C3
```

Expected result

```
A    B    C    Csub2  Csub3  Csub4
P1   1    Nan  C1
P2   3    Nan  Nan    Nan    C2
P3   2    Nan  Nan    C3
```

Any help will be appreciated Thank You

Comment: Why value for `B` changes from 4 to 3 for `A=P2` ?

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of one-hot encoding? Checkout [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) in pandas? A clearer idea of why trying to format like this may help

Comment: @harvpan sorry it was a typo.  Corrected it.  Thanks

Comment: @KenSyme this is just for excel formatting, indentation is very useful visual aid while reading large Bill Of Materials (BOM).  This form gets color-coded and gets printed on paper.  Indentation or formatting of this kind may seem unnecessary for the majority but they are a lifesaver when you're trying to make data readable to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in pandas you can do with `pivot`

```
pd.concat([df.assign(C=np.nan),df.pivot(columns='B',values='C')],axis=1)
Out[89]: 
    A  B   C    1    2    3
0  P1  1 NaN   C1  NaN  NaN
1  P2  3 NaN  NaN  NaN   C2
2  P3  2 NaN  NaN   C3  NaN
```

---

Update

```
s=pd.DataFrame([[np.nan]*x+y for x,y  in zip(df.B,df.loc[:,'C':].values.tolist())],index=df.index)
df=pd.concat([df,s],1)
df
Out[1007]: 
    A  B   C   0    1     2     3
0  P1  1  C1 NaN   C1  None  None
1  P2  3  C2 NaN  NaN   NaN    C2
2  P3  2  C3 NaN  NaN    C3  None
```

Comment: very clever way of doing this. :)

Comment: @Wen-Ben it's a nice workaround for the example I had.  However, it seems to be not a good solution when column C expands and have column D and both of them have to move together.  do you have any ideas for that

Comment: @Shri you can just repeat above `pd.concat([df.assign(C=np.nan,'D'),df.pivot(columns='B',values='C'),df.pivot(columns='B',values='D')],axis=1)
`

Comment: @Wen-Ben concat does not work for what I was talking abou.   <br/> The df i was looking for is like this   `0  P1  1 NaN C1 D1`  <br/>  `0 P2 3 NaN NaN NaN C2 D2`